# JASIG CAS: single sign out not working

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, single-sign-on, cas

I have single sign on working beautifully, but single sign-out is not working.

The scenario is like this:

1. Open webapp1 and get redirected to CAS login page
2. Enter details and login
3. Open webapp2 which also uses CAS. Automatically logs in, as the user already signed in.
4. Log out of webapp1
5. Try to open webapp1 or webapp2 (in another tab) redirects you back to the login page.
6. However, the session to webapp2 in step 3 is not closed and the user can still use the application without any problems. How do I automatically invalidate the session when the user signs out?

The log off button for both applications first call `session.invalidate()` and then redirects to `https://localhost:8443/cas/logout`

The single sign out filter is the first filter in the web.xml file.  I also have the `SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener` in web.xml.

Following is the extract from my web.xml

```
<!-- CAS settings -->
<!-- Use filter init-param if your container does not support context params. 
    CAS Authentication Filter and CAS Validation Filter need a serverName init-param 
    in lieu of a context-param definition. -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>serverName</param-name>
    <param-value>https://localhost:8443</param-value>
</context-param>

  <!-- Facilitates CAS single sign-out -->
  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!--
  CAS client filters
  Single sign-out filter MUST come first since it needs to be evaluated
  before other filters.
  -->
  <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <!--
        IMPORTANT:
        Use Saml11AuthenticationFilter for version 3.1.12 and later.
        Use org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter for previous
        versions.
        -->
        <filter-class>
              org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.Saml11AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
              <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
              <param-value>https://localhost:8443/cas/login</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>service</param-name>
        <param-value>https://localhost:8443/JAdaptiv/default.action</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
              org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
              <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
              <param-value>https://localhost:8443/cas</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
              <param-name>redirectAfterValidation</param-name>
              <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
              <!-- Leniency of time checking in ms when validating SAML assertions. Consider 
                    setting this parameter more liberally if you anticipate system clock drift 
                    on your application servers relative to the CAS server. The default is 1000 
                    (1s) and at least one person had problems with drift at that small a tolerance 
                    value. A good approach is to start low and then increase by 1000 as needed 
                    until problems stop. Note that increasing this value may have negative security 
                    implications. Consider fixing clock drift problems as an alternative. -->
              <param-name>tolerance</param-name>
              <param-value>1000</param-value>
        </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
              org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I have this exact problem, did you find the solution?

Comment: I have this exact problem, did you find the solution?

Comment: @Croydon Dias, do you use stateful or stateless Spring Java application ?

Answer (score 2):

I also had another issue with standard CAS protocol, where single sign-out worked on an integration server but not from localhost.

Scenario

- log into both `http://my-app-dev/app` and `http://localhost:8080/app` with CAS on `http://my-cas/cas`
- log out of CAS `http://my-cas/cas/logout`
- `http://my-app-dev/app` now bounces me to CAS
- `http://localhost:8080` - still logged in!

I suspect the reason is the CAS server couldn't send a sign-out message to `localhost:8080` because `localhost` is resolved in the *CAS* server's context, so it doesn't actually talk to my local dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. We had a java and a php client. When I went to `http://mycasserver/logout` only the java client logged out.

For the single sign out to work in the php client, you have to change:

```
phpCAS::handleLogoutRequests();
```

for

```
phpCAS::handleLogoutRequests(false);
```

And Voila! 
Refer to the documentation at [phpCAS examples](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS+examples)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SAML 1.1 protocol be sure that you included the `artifactParameterName` parameter

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Configuring+Single+Sign+Out

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>artifactParameterName</param-name>
      <param-value>SAMLart</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had basically the same configuration for my application before I switched to the spring configuration. I had a look on the SVN and basically the only difference to your config is the use of the [Single Sign Out Listener](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Configuring+Single+Sign+Out)

```
listener>
    <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Could this work for you? Of course don't forget to add it on both WebApps if it works.

UPDATE:
I found the description of the listener in the [docs](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/jasig/cas/cas-client-core/3.1.7/cas-client-core-3.1.7-javadoc.jar!/org/jasig/cas/client/session/SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener.html), and it should do what's missing in your setting

Comment: But I do have the SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener in my spring config.

Comment: I have the single sign out listener added to both webapps. I downloaded the source for cas-client-core and added a few debugging statements. It seems that when you logout off webapp1, only the SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener for webapp1 is called, not webapp2.

Comment: Have you found the solution in the meantime?

Comment: I have changed jobs since I asked this question. However, we had still not found a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that the CAS server can send a HTTP request to your webapp. Have a look in the logs of the CAS server.