# Jasig-CAS single sign out issue with Java clients

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, single-sign-on, cas

I have a CAS 3.5 server and two Java clients (let's call them app1 and app2) and I'm having trouble getting single sign out to work.
app1 and app2 are deployed in different instances of JBoss AS7.

The test case scenario is:

1 - In a browser tab, login successfully to app1.

2 - In an other tab, upon accessing app2, user is already logged in. (Single Sign On works).

3 - Succesful logout of app1.

4 - However, user continues to be logged in app2 even after page refreshes. JSESSIONID cookie still exists.

When logging out of app1 (step3), this gets printed on app2's console (log level: debug):

```
08:15:42,806 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.Saml11AuthenticationFilter] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-3) no ticket and no assertion found
08:15:42,807 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.Saml11AuthenticationFilter] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-3) Constructed service url: http://myip:8080/app2
08:15:42,807 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.Saml11AuthenticationFilter] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-3) redirecting to "https://mycasip:8443/cas/login?TARGET=http%3A%2F%2Fmyip%3A8080%2Fapp2"
```

Just for the record, both cas server's and app2's URL seem to be constructed fine, however, no actual redirection happens.
I can't see anything printed on cas server's console (again log level: debug)

Here's an extract from my web.xml (I use SAML to send an ldap attribute besides username):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>artifactParameterName</param-name>
        <param-value>SAMLart</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

There is no filter definition before SingleSignOutFilter, only the app display-name and welcome-file-list.

I have read similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125527/jasig-cas-single-sign-out-not-working?rq=1)(Note: I don't use spring nor jsp and user is still logged in after opening app2 in a new tab) but solutions didn't work for me or weren't given at all.